# Fit DataGridView columns into table

Tags: c#, winforms

I want the Columns to FIT into the DataGridView Table. I have like 5-6 columns, and when I maximize the Form, the DataGrid table looks so empty...
like this :
[image]

but i want it to look something like this :
[image]

I know it looks ugly now... but some other fields will be added :). I just want to know if it is possible to AUTOSIZE the columns to fill the table ? 
Oh and btw... it's because I don't want the user to allow resizing the columns.

Comment: Check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5429/Auto-sizing-DataGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You can change the `AutoSizeMode` property of the column to `Fill`. And please note that set the `AutoSizeMode` property does **not** disable column resizing. Change the respective property (I guess `AllowColumnResize` or something) to `false`.